# Autofill q-input color in Quasar Framework

Tags: forms, input, autocomplete, autofill, quasar

When using autofill on a QInput in Quasar, the background color looks weirdly different, like this:

[image: Auto-filled input fields have a different background color]

I tried to upgrade the Quasar version and search for different solutions to sort out this but couldn't find anything.

How can I ensure that the background color doesn't look different when the input control is filled it via autofill vs. when typing in values manually?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the problem by adding this style:

```
<style>
 input {
  background-clip: text !important;
  -webkit-background-clip: text !important;
}
</style>
```

[image: Input fields with regular background color after auto-fill]